# How do I redirect from a vanity URL to my acutal site?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a website where the client controls the DNS and I control the web server. They recently purchased a vanity url and they want it to redirect to the actual site.

I am trying `rewrite https://vanityurl.com$ / redirect;` in nginx but I am getting sent to a "your connection is not private" page I have ssl set up for the actual site. Do I need to set it up for the vanity as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting will result in the end-user's browser changing the URL and making a new request to whatever is returned in the "location" header. If you want to redirect to a different URL you can do so like this:

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name vanityurl.com www. vanityurl.com;
  return      301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

where example.com is your new site you want to send people to. But like i said it will change the URL.

If you want to "mask" the old url, you'll need to set up a proxy, unless you run both services, in which case you can just create a new NGINX `server` block and handle requests to your new domain. (be advised you'll need to sort out SSL. It appears thats the issue you're facing now, that the server is serving its content with an SSL certificate that does not match the request hostname.)

You will also need a corresponding handler for requests coming to port 443 (if you're terminating the SSL on your server, rather than with an upstream load balancer or something).

Here is the difference between redirecting and rewriting in NGINX: http://think-devops.com/blogs/nginx-rewrite-redirect.html and more generally:
https://blogs.iis.net/owscott/url-rewrite-vs-redirect-what-s-the-difference

Comment: Thank you so much Jp! Adding the server block with the 301 redirect worked for me. The blog you sent over looks like it has some really good information, I am definitely saving that for later reading.